# @FetchRequest does not refresh the View

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a CoreData File that contains two entities. I'm experiencing an issue when trying to fetch items from these entities. Fetching items from the first entity works fine, but I'm encountering problems with the second entity.

In one of my views, I fetch and display the first entity in a list successfully. However, when I try to show the second entity in a different view using a @FetchRequest, the view doesn't refresh and display the data. I have to restart the app for all the data and items to appear.

Interestingly, when I have two or more items from the second entity fetched and I delete one of them, the view refreshes properly. But if I try to delete the last item, the view doesn't refresh.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

First Fetch-Request:
`@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [ NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FirstEntity.name, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "finished == %d AND consumed == %d", true, false) ) var firstResult: FetchedResults<FirstEntity>`

Second Fetch-Request:
`@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [ NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SecondEntity.created, ascending: true)]) var secondResult: FetchedResults<SecondEntity>`

My View-Code:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectConetext

@ObservedObject var item: SecondEntity

var body: some View {
    ZStack (alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .top)) {
        HStack {
            if let data = item.image {
                let uiimage = UIImage(data: data)
                if uiimage != nil {
                    Image(uiImage: uiimage!)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding()
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "questionmark.app")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding()
                }
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "questionmark.app")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .padding()
            }
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                
                if let name = item.name {
                    Text(name)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(Color(activeColor))
                        .padding(4)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                } else {
                    Text("No Name")
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(activeColor))
                        .padding(4)
                }
                
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.exclamationmark")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.headline)
                    
                    Text("•")
                    
                    if let date = item.date {
                        Text(date, style: .date)
                    } else {
                        Text("No date")
                    }
                }
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                
                
                HStack (spacing: 15) {
                    if item.consumed == false {
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            ZStack {
                                ZStack {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(.green)
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                    }
                    
                    if item.consumed == true {
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            ZStack {
                                ZStack {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(.orange)
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                    }
                    
                    if item.consumed == false {
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            ZStack {
                                ZStack {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(.blue)
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 1)
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(.red)
                                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                
                                Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(4)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
   }

private func deleteFoodItem() {
    DataController().deleteFoodItem(foodItem: currentFoodItem, context: managedObjectConetext)
}
```

Comment: All CoreData objects have to be wrapped with “@ObservedObject” to see changes.

Comment: What do you mean, does it not work when I pass the managedObjectContext in the Environment?

Comment: No it does not you have to observe every ObservableObject/CoreData object at every level as of now at least. iOS 17 might make this a little easier.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would help if you posted the view code where this is happening.

Comment: A few of things: First, you have shown us your detail view, but not the parent view with the `@FetchRequest`. Next, you do not need to wrap the `item` in an `@ObservedObject` in this view. It will be updated if the `@FetchRequest` is properly coded. Lastly, `DataController().deleteFoodItem()` creates a NEW `DataController`, rather than reusing your current one. That may be fine, depending upon how it is coded, but be careful doing things like that. You can end up with weird behaviors, like the entity not deleting. Also, deleting the item you are view can also leave your view in a bad state.